# How do I disable parameter hints in Vscode

Tags: php, visual-studio-code

I am coding in PHP in Vscode 1.56.2 which I believe is the latest update and when I hover over, say, the word 'Class' I get a pop-up explaining what a class is. From the Vscode website I am advised to disable this behaviour by going to settings and set

"editor.parameterHints": false,

but in my settings I have:

"editor.parameterHints.enabled": false,

and it is not disabling the popups. I have tried deleting the '.enabled' but it seems to make no difference. Can anyone give me the solution?

Comment: Do you have any PHP extensions installed and enabled in visual studio code? It's possible those have their own settings that handle the same functionality

Comment: You mean the annoying suggestions thing?, if so its `"editor.quickSuggestions": false,`